# Estimating the posterior of a parameter vector which is only observed after linear transformation

Tags: stan, pystan

I have a known matrix `M` (square of dimension `D`) and a parameter vector `v` (of length `D`) which is unknown to me and whose posterior distribution I am trying to estimate.  My prior on `v` is that each of its components is standard normal.

For example, let's say that `M` looks like this:

```
[[1, -1, -1]
 [1,  0,  2]
 [1,  1, -1]]
```

My observed data is a of the form `R * M * v` where `R` is a "reduction" (non-square) matrix that effectively only allows me to observe some of the components of `M * v`.  For example, R might look like this (keeping the first and second components of `M * v`):

```
[[1,  0,  0]
 [0,  1,  0]]
```

What's the right way to set up a problem like this in STAN?

Comment: A Stan program codes a log density equal to the posterior up to a constant.  The standard way to do that is to code the log joint density of the data and parameters, which is equal to the posterior up to a constant by Bayes's rule.  The joint log density is usually coded as the log prior plus log likelihood.  You need to specify a likelihood for the observations to complete the Bayesian model.  You have a prior p(v) and need a likelihood p(R * M * v | M, v) to complete the model.

Comment: `P(R * M * v | M, V) = 1` since all `R` does is select a subset of the dimensions from `M * v`.

Comment: You need a likelihood at least fo the parameters, i.e., `p(v | ...)`.  Stan isn't a constraint solver---it's a statistical inference engine, so it needs some probabilistic model in which to operate.